# Efficient intersection detection between disks with identical radius

Tags: time-complexity, optimization, computational-geometry, euclidean-distance

I have a set of $N$ points randomly positionned on a rectangular space (btw with either absorbing, reflecting or wrapping boundaries), and I need to obtain the distances between every 2 points whose distance is at most $2\,r$.

This is akin to consider every point as a disk with radius $r$ and only consider distances between centers of intersecting disks. I know that people doing [collision detection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_detection) are very much into optimizing the detection of intersecting shapes, but it seems that I can make hypotheses that they cannot make in general, and that would maybe help me not to test every 2 points together:

- There is no motion, only the set of static disks.
- All shapes are disks.
- All disks have the same radius $r$.
- I have a *hint* that the average distance between 2 neighbouring points is much smaller than $r$, so it will be frequent that numerous disks overlap together.

Are there clever ways to prune among the $\left(\begin{array}{c}N \\ 2\end{array}\right)$ pairs of points and (at best) only calculate distance between points whose disks are intersecting.. or likely to intersect together?

Comment: This looks like a job for a [spatial partition](http://www.gameprogrammingpatterns.com/spatial-partition.html).

Comment: On top of @DMGregory's comment, given that the disks are static, a *regular* partition (i.e. splitting the rectangular space into a grid rectangles) may well be the most efficient method here. Ideally, you would use a grid where the cells are as close to square in shape as possible, and where the number of cells is roughly $N$.

Comment: @DMGregory Thank you, I'll have a look into this :)

Comment: @Pseudonym Thank you as well. Do you have any explanation why $N$ *regular* and *squared* cells would be the most beneficial?

Comment: @iago-lito Using $N$ cells means the space usage, and amortised search time, is linear. Using square-shaped cells makes the cell shape as close as practical to a circle, which is the shape that you actually want to search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use any standard data structure / algorithm for [nearest neighbor search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbor_search).  In particular, you are interested in the [fixed-radius nearest neighbor problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-radius_near_neighbors), for which there are many algorithms.

Comment: I'll also have a look into these, thank you :) Do you happen to know how the nearest neighbour approach compares to spatial partitionning?

Comment: @iago-lito, spatial partitioning is one approach to nearest neighbor search, particularly fixed-radius nearest neighbor search.